# eloquent where by fk value (using with)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables

```
users:
id, name

posts:
id, user_id, text
```

How can I query all posts by a user by it's name rather than id. Something like this:

```
Post::with('user')->where('name','Peter')
```

EDIT:

I discovered that it is better to start the query from Users instead:

```
User::where('name','Peter')->first()->Posts();
```

However, calling first() executes a separate query and Posts a second one. Is it possible to have everything in one sql call to the db?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **query builder** and do something like this:

```
$posts = DB::table('users')
             ->join('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
             ->where('name','Peter')
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you define a relationship? Users to posts is one to many... In your user model, add the relationship to posts...

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Then you can query all posts for a user this way...

```
$user = App\User::where('name', 'Peter')->first();

foreach ($user->posts as p) {
    //
}
```

Take a look at the relationship documentation, relationships in Eloquent are real nice and not to difficult to figure out...

If you want to eager load the relationship you can do it with the with() function... this will eager load the relationship...

```
$user = App\User::with('posts')->where('name', 'Peter')->first();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this approach uses lazy loading and causes even more db queries than the two I already have in the solution in my question

Comment: Just eager load the relationship with the with() function then. See the edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following syntax creates a single query:

```
Post::whereHas('User', function($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'Peter');
        })->get();
```